# C++ approach to configuration without macro

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, configuration, abstract-class

I am implementing a library, and using abstract class/interface which has some different implementations. I want to allow user to select particular implementation using a config file e.g. `config.h`. I have two questions:

- How to achieve this without macro ?
- I am using inheritance to implement the subclasses, but I do not want to dynamically select the class at runtime, can we still achieve this?

I am looking for c++11 solution, but c++14 and c++17 is welcome too.

As an example:

```
#include "config.h"

class library1_base {
  virtual void blah() = 0;
  virtual void bleh() = 0;
}

#ifdef LIB1_USE_IMPL1
class impl1_lib1 : library1_base { ... };
using library1 = impl1_lib;
#else
class impl2_lib1 : library1_base { ... };
using library1 = impl2_lib;
#endif

class library2_base {
  virtual void ah() = 0;
  virtual void oh() = 0;
}

#ifdef LIB2_USE_IMPL1
class impl1_lib2 : library2_base { ... };
using library2 = impl1_lib2;
#else
class impl2_lib2 : library2_base { ... };
using library2 = impl2_lib2;
#endif
```

`config.h` is as follows (using macro)

```
#define LIB1_USE_IMPL1
#define LIB2_USE_IMPL2
```

How they use:

```
library1 x; // now this library1 should be using impl1_lib1
x.blah();
x.bleh();
library2 y; // now this library2 should be using impl2_lib2
y.ah();
y.oh();
```

Comment: downvoter.. please comment so that I can improve my question.

Comment: You must display sample code to display your goal you wish. Someone is going to flag your post most likely.

Comment: OK @NickPavini added an example using macro to do what I want

Comment: Why don't you want to use macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, ask yourself "how am I going to select config and why?"

Macros are ubiquitous (you can define them both as compiler flags and in code), but they lack scoping capabilities (they are global and cannot be, for example, defined as namespace-local), so they are prone to name collisions.

If the latter is your concern, you can define a special config class(es) with typedefs/constants, like this:

```
namespace myapp {
   struct Config {
      class library : library_base { ... }
      using other_library = some_other_library;
      using version_t = int;
      static const version_t VERSION = 1;
   }
}
```

But to select desired config, you'll have to include one of multiple configXXX.h files, or make config class template and have multiple specializations for each configuration, like this:

```
enum class ConfigType {
   JPEG, PNG
};
template <ConfigType type> struct Configs;
template <> struct Configs<ConfigType::JPEG> {
   using library = libjpeg;
};
template <> struct Configs<ConfigType::PNG> {
   using library = libpng;
};
...
static const ConfigType CONFIG_TYPE = ConfigType::JPEG;
...
using Config = Configs<CONFIG_TYPE>;
using library = Config::library;
```

**Update #1:** In later example, a composition seems like the best solution (I've renamed things, so they make a little more sense):

```
// configs.hpp
enum class AudioType {
   MP3, OGG
};
template <AudioType type> struct AudioConfigs;
template <> struct AudioConfigs<AudioType::MP3> {
   using Library = libmp3; // of course, you can define class in-place instead of typedef
};
template <> struct AudioConfigs<AudioType::OGG> {
   using Library = libvorbis;
};

enum class ImageType {
   JPEG, PNG
};
template <ImageType type> struct ImageConfigs;
template <> struct ImageConfigs<ImageType::JPEG> {
   using Library = libjpeg;
};
template <> struct ImageConfigs<ImageType::PNG> {
   using Library = pnglib;
};

template <AudioType audiotype, ImageType imagetype> struct Configs {
   using AudioLibrary = typename AudioConfigs<audiotype>::Library;
   using ImageLibrary = typename ImageConfigs<imagetype>::Library;
};

// config_setup.hpp - this one you will edit
#include "configs.hpp"
using Config = Configs<AudioType::MP3, ImageType::JPEG>;

// config.hpp
#include "config_setup.hpp"
using AudioLibrary = typename Config::AudioLibrary;
using ImageLibrary = typename Config::ImageLibrary;

// real code
#include "config.hpp"
AudioLibrary audioLibrary;
audioLibrary.doStuff();
```

Alternative structure:

```
template <AudioType audiotype, ImageType imagetype> struct Configs {
   using Audio = typename AudioConfigs<audiotype>;
   using Image = typename ImageConfigs<imagetype>;
};
// Options should be accessed like Config::Audio::Library now
```

**Update #2:** <s>(Just to illustrate endless possibilities) With some variadic template magic, you can shorten AudioConfigs/ImageConfigs/etc. to:</s>

```
template <AudioConfig config> struct AudioConfigs : public LibraryConfigs<AudioConfig, config, AudioType::MP3, AudioType::OGG, libmp3, libvorbis> { };
```

...completely avoiding boilerplate code with multiple specializations. You will then lose possibility to define classes in-place and this is what you're doing in your examples, so cross that.

Comment: This approach doesn't scale, since I have to specify specialization for all possible configurations e.g. what if I have more than 1 configurable library ?

Comment: In fact, it is the most covenient/flexible/scalable approach you can imagine, because, you can have multiple config classes, then you can inherit, compose, typedef, specialize any of them to form any imaginable configuration structure. If you want more in-depth explanations, please provide some examples with how will you do it with macros and what shotcomings are you willing to overcome.

Comment: Thanks for helping Dmitry, I added example with two libraries, could you adjust your idea.

Comment: I see.. didn't think of using a combination like that :). will wait for a while to accept in case I found something less verbose.